# Логгирование в браузере

Tags: node.js, vue.js, логирование

Задача. На фронте, в браузере что-то отвалилось. Требуется лог от браузера собирать и складывать в loghouse, например. Есть ли какие-нибудь решения, которые занимаются такой задачей. Сейчас мы смотрим в сторону создания отдельного сервиса, который будет принимать запросы от фронта, в случае неполадок в браузере. Далее, этот сервис будет складывать логи в loghouse.

Comment: Мы используем https://sentry.io/signup/?trial&plan=medium&period=annual&utm_source=syndication&utm_medium=blog&utm_content=sitepoint&utm_campaign=sponsorship и https://www.npmjs.com/package/raven-js.

Comment: @IliaBrykin бесплатные аналоги есть?

Comment: Можете посмотреть https://www.npmjs.com/package/stacktrace-js, но я не использовал.

Comment: Есть еще один крутой проект, с возможностью записи видео и дебажить в виртуальном браузере, но он тоже платный.((( Если интересно, то могу на работе ссылку посмотреть.

Comment: @IliaBrykin о, не фига. Давайте. Был бы очень признателен

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил оформить свои комментарии в качестве ответа. 
Мы используем **Raven.js** https://www.npmjs.com/package/raven-js и https://sentry.io/signup/?trial&plan=medium&period=annual&utm_source=syndication&utm_medium=blog&utm_content=sitepoint&utm_campaign=sponsorship

Есть бесплатный аналог **stacktrace.js**, но мы с ним не работали. npmjs.com/package/stacktrace-js

И крутой вариант, https://therootcause.io/ как обещал, Этот проект представляли на vue.js конференции в Амстердаме в прошлом году. Эта фирма выступала в качестве спонсора. Здесь демо  https://app.therootcause.io/sandbox/vue/#/admin/dashboard